# combine multidimensional array into key based dictionary object

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, list, dictionary

I am trying to create a price schema for a product, basing on its color, size and material. 
My current way of implementation is to maintain 1 JSON object which contains all the options and trying to generate another JSON object using all possible combination of its options.
For example

```
var productOption = {
  "color":["red","green","yellow"],
  "size":["S","M","L"],
  "material":["leather","linen"]
}

what I want to create something like follow

[
  {
  "red":{
    "S":{
      "leather":{
        "cost":100,"available":true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
  "green":{
    "S":{
      "leather":{
        "cost":100,"available":true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  ....

]
```

so I can do something like price["red"]["S"]["leather"] to access the price for red color, leather, in small size.
Is there a easy way to do it? either in Javascript or Python.

**EDIT:**

What if some product only has color and size or color only?

```
var productOption= { color :[...],size:[...]};
```

**EDIT 2:**

I made up following code to solve my issue. If you have any suggestion on how I can improve my code. Please let me know.

```
// I am using lodash for those underscore signs.
var processPrice = function(){
  price = {};
  var keys = _.keys(_.pick(priceOption,function(value,key){
    return !_.isEmpty(value);
  }));
  if(keys.length>0){
    genMatrix(keys,[],price);  
  }
};
var genMatrix = function(keys,options,obj){
  var key = keys[0];
  if(keys.length>1){
    var subKeys = _.compact(keys);
      subKeys.shift();
    _.each(priceOption[key],function(opt){
      var subOption = _.compact(options);
      subOption.push(opt.value);
      obj[opt.value]={};
      genMatrix(subKeys,subOption,obj[opt.value]); 
    });
  }else{
    _.each(priceOption[key],function(opt){
      obj[opt.value]={cost: 100, available: true};
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Where is the data coming from i.e. where and how are the values for (say) [red][S][leather] coming from?

Comment: @JayanthKoushik  if you refer to the cost and availability information, that is manually entered by ourselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python version

```
from itertools import product
result = []
for col, siz, mat in product(*(data["color"], data["size"], data["material"])):
    result.append({col: {siz: {mat: {'available': True, 'cost': 100}}}})
print result
```

**Output**

```
[{'red': {'S': {'leather': {'available': True, 'cost': 100}}}},
 {'red': {'S': {'linen': {'available': True, 'cost': 100}}}},
 {'red': {'M': {'leather': {'available': True, 'cost': 100}}}},
 {'red': {'M': {'linen': {'available': True, 'cost': 100}}}},
 {'red': {'L': {'leather': {'available': True, 'cost': 100}}}},
 {'red': {'L': {'linen': {'available': True, 'cost': 100}}}},
 {'green': {'S': {'leather': {'available': True, 'cost': 100}}}},
 {'green': {'S': {'linen': {'available': True, 'cost': 100}}}},
 {'green': {'M': {'leather': {'available': True, 'cost': 100}}}},
 {'green': {'M': {'linen': {'available': True, 'cost': 100}}}},
 {'green': {'L': {'leather': {'available': True, 'cost': 100}}}},
 {'green': {'L': {'linen': {'available': True, 'cost': 100}}}},
 {'yellow': {'S': {'leather': {'available': True, 'cost': 100}}}},
 {'yellow': {'S': {'linen': {'available': True, 'cost': 100}}}},
 {'yellow': {'M': {'leather': {'available': True, 'cost': 100}}}},
 {'yellow': {'M': {'linen': {'available': True, 'cost': 100}}}},
 {'yellow': {'L': {'leather': {'available': True, 'cost': 100}}}},
 {'yellow': {'L': {'linen': {'available': True, 'cost': 100}}}}]
```

JavaScript version:

```
var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data["color"].length; i += 1) {
    var color = data["color"][i];
    for (var j = 0; j < data["size"].length; j += 1) {
        var size = data["size"][j];
        for (var k = 0; k < data["material"].length; k += 1) {
            var material = data["material"][k], obj = {};
            obj[color] = {};
            obj[color][size] = {};
            obj[color][size][material] = {cost: 100, available: true};
            result.push(obj);
        }
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: +1 for `product` and `zip`, but couldn't everything inside the loop be done more plainly: `result.append({col: {siz: {mat: {'available': True, 'cost': 100}}}})`.

Comment: @FMc Brilliant... Thanks man :) I included it in the answer :)

Comment: @thefourtheye, is it possible to have a Javascript version?

Comment: @thefourtheye one last question, what if the options are dynamic? means if we don't know ahead of time what will be the keys (color,size,material) in the **productionOption** array.